# Generating PDF using pdfkit in Google App Engine raises AttributeError for Popen

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pdf, flask, pdfkit

I am trying to generate a PDF using pdfkit in Flask. pdfkit is working fine locally but when I use it in Google App Engine it raises the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\flaskapp\flask\app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\flaskapp\flask\app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python27\flaskapp\flask\app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\flaskapp\flask\app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Python27\flaskapp\main.py", line 17, in yout
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(my_string,False , configuration=config)
  File "C:\Python27\flaskapp\pdfkit\api.py", line 68, in from_string
    return r.to_pdf(output_path)
  File "C:\Python27\flaskapp\pdfkit\pdfkit.py", line 92, in to_pdf
    result = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Popen'
```

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, request, render_template
import pdfkit

path_wkthmltopdf = r'C:\Python27\flaskapp\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'

config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkthmltopdf)
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/pdf', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def pdf():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_string = request.form['text11']
        pdf = pdfkit.from_string(my_string, False, configuration=config)

        response = make_response(pdf)
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=out.pdf'

        return response

    return render_template('pdff.html')
```

Comment: did you ended finding a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

This code won't run on Google App Engine, because App Engine's [Python runtime environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime) doesn't allow calls to `subprocess.Popen` or any other call that starts another process.

Comment: Don't use App Engine?

Comment: There's nothing specifically wrong with App Engine. You can use anything you want inside the "flexible" environment.

Comment: don't use appengine, in any such cases appengine is useless.